# I'm trying to change a line of a file in Python, but the content just disappears

Tags: python, file, text, text-files

First of all this is my oode:

```
c = open('Tasks//Task_Counter.txt', 'r+')
okay = c.read().splitlines()

which_task = int(okay[0])
this_task = which_task + 1 

which_port = int(okay[1])
this_port = which_port + 1

c.truncate(0)
c.close()

c = open('Tasks//Task_Counter.txt', 'r+')
okay = c.read().splitlines()

c.write(str(this_task))
c.write("\n")
c.write(str(this_port))

c.close()

f = open("Tasks//task"+ str(this_task) +".py","w+")
q = open('Tasks//task_maker.py', 'r+')


for line in q:
    f.write(line)    

new_file_lines = f.read().splitlines()

line13 = new_file_lines[12]

line13.write("this_browser = "+str(this_port))

q.close()
f.close()
```

Basically the first part is creating a new Python file with the content of 'task_maker.py'. That works perfectly fine. The only problem is that when I'm trying to change anything of the new created Python file, that the content of it disappears. Even closing and opening it again leads to that problem.
Anybody who can solve this?

Comment: Constantly rewriting a text file is inefficient and brittle. Try using a simple database like SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `write`  you can used `append`.

```
line13.append("this_browser = "+str(this_port))
```

Comment: When I try that it gives me that Error:     line13 = new_file_lines[12]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: line13 = new_file_lines[:12]

Comment: Add list slice [:12]

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't give me an error, but it just not add the text to line 13.